# Having multiple Update functions on one single component

Tags: unity-game-engine, inheritance

My Problem is that I have 2 Update functions on one single component
I have a script called Player and a script called duck
The duck script is linked to the play script with inheritance

```cs
public class Duck : Player
{
    public float duckFlyForce;
    private void Update()
    {
        Fly();
    }
  
    void Fly()
    { 
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !gC.isGround)
        {
             playerRB.velocity = Vector2.up * duckFlyForce;
        }

    }
}
```

```cs
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private void Start()
    {
        Assign();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        Input();
    }
...
```

That's the simple Version of both script

I need to use Update in both scripts
if I put the Input in the FixedUpdate it doesn't work because it needs to be updated every frame

Now my Problem is that the Update function in the Duck script doesn't work
The other one runs without any problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve this issue is by using the `virtual` keyword.  This allows the member to be overridden in a derived class.  You also need to change the access modifier to `protected` in order for the derived type to see the class member.  The derived class can `override` the function and provide its own implementation.  You can use `base.Update()` to call the function on the base class.

```cs
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        Assign();
    }
    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        Input();
    }
}

public class Duck : Player
{
    public float duckFlyForce;

    protected override void Update()
    {
        base.Update(); // executes Update in the base class

        Fly();
    }
}
```